# Django Get a variable from one application view to another application view

Tags: python, django, session, microservices

I have two different apps in django project where I have views:**auths/views.py** on this path I have:

```
def home(request):
    users = CustomUser.objects.all()
    events = Event.objects.all()
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    event_categorys = EventCategory.objects.all()
    tickets = Ticket.objects.all()

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        email = request.user.email
    else:
        email = 'AnonymousUser'
    if request.method == "GET":
        url = request.get_full_path()
        code_index = url.find('code=')
        if code_index != -1:
            code = url[code_index + 5:]
            print("Code is :", code)
            request.session['code'] = code
            session_code = code
        else:
            session_code = request.session.get('code')

        get_bearer_token(request)
        print("ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss: ", session_code)

    return render(request, 'home.html',
                  context={'events': events, 'tags': tags, 'event_categorys': event_categorys, 'tickets': tickets,
                           'session_code': session_code})
```

and on this path **BogID/views.py** I have this code :

```
def get_bearer_token(request):
    # Define the authentication endpoint URL
    auth_url = "https://account-test.bog.ge/auth/realms/bog-id/protocol/openid-connect/token"

    session_code = request.session.get('session_code')

    if session_code:
        print("Session Code:", session_code)
    else:
        print("Session Code not found")

    payload = {
        "grant_type": session_code,
        "client_id": "your_client_id",
        "client_secret": "your_client_secret"
    }

    response = requests.post(auth_url,data=payload)

    return HttpResponse("asdasd")
```

I am getting the token from the URL in the **home** view, and giving this code to `session_code` variable, and I am trying to get this variable value with the `get_bearer_token` view, but it can't see this code in session. Is it because of that they are not in the same app? How can I solve this problem? It is giving me **"Session Code not found"** all the time. I have tested the home view and it get the code correctly and gives that code to the variable I declared correctly.

Comment: In your home view... if the request url ends with something like `?code=12345` or `?...<stuff>...&code=12345` (the part after the `?` is called the querystring) then there is a much simpler way to extract the code value: `code = request.GET["code"]` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET Django automatically parses the querystring data into a dictionary-like object for you

Comment: (and instead of `if code_index != -1:` you can `if "code" in request.GET:`)

Comment: The actual problem you asked about... in `get_bearer_token ` view you are accessing a different session value `request.session.get('session_code')` to the one you set in the `home` view `request.session['code'] = code` so it will always be empty

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for your answer,so i need to change session_code = request.session.get('session_code') to session_code = request.session.get('code') and this will work right?

Comment: It looks like that should fix it

Comment: @Anentropic Nah mate,It is giving the same message -"Session Code not found"

Comment: what is printed by `print("Code is :", code)` in the other view?

Comment: @Anentropic It is the same code(token) as in session_code variable

Comment: the session data is not saved until just before the http response is returned (see https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L59) so if you are checking what is printed by the `get_bearer_token(request)` call in `home` view that will never work, you need to make a separate request to the `get_bearer_token` view after `home` has returned its response

Comment: (generally you don't want to be calling one view from another view, instead factor out the relevant code into a separate function)

Comment: @Anentropic I think "get_bearer_token(request)" was doing nothing there,it was the test code from the code i wrote there before and forgot to delete,i deleted it now and it is giving the same code not found massage

Comment: so you make a request (from browser or whatever) to `home` view, it extracts and sets the `code` to the session ok, then you make a request to `get_bearer_token` view (in same browser) and it prints `"Session Code not found"`?  which session backend are you using?  are you stopping and starting the server between the two requests?

Comment: @Anentropic no I am not stoping anything,So look.I am using an API,I sent info on that api and authorise there,after that it redirects me to the home view page where i get the code from the url,after that i want to get the token so i have the get_bearer_token view where i want to send the info to server with that token too.I am using "SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'"

Comment: if you `print(request.session.session_key)` from both views do they have the same value?

Comment: @Anentropic It gives None in both views

Comment: @Anentropic Update:I was not saving the session,after I added request.session.save() in both views now i can see the session key and those keys are different

Comment: you shouldn't have to manually save, you are probably missing the required session middleware in your settings? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#enabling-sessions

Comment: @Anentropic Nope I have it already "MIDDLEWARE = ['django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',]

Comment: If the session keys are different it explains why you get "Session Code not found" - it's reading from a different session. The key is stored in the browser as a cookie, when the cookie is sent on a subsequent request it tells Django which session to load (if no cookie sent create new session).  If you are using different browser window for each request it might be a problem. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#browser-length-sessions-vs-persistent-sessions You might try the test here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#setting-test-cookies

Comment: @Anentropic I am doing it in 1 tab only,Process: First of all i open incognito window and go to localhost/bog/auth where i authenticate and after that it returns me to the homepage where i am getting the token from the url,after that i go to another url -> localhost/bog/token - where i want to get that token